# How to enable history search by page up/down in git bash like in Linux?

Tags: windows, git-bash

I want my git bash to search history by page up/page down like in Ubuntu.

I tried to simply create a ~/.bashrc with this:

```
    "\e[A":history-search-backward
    "\e[B":history-search-forward
```

or this:

```
    "\e[5~": history-search-backward   
    "\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

but it doesn't work. Of course.

Does anyone knows is it even possible?

Comment: Have you tried just ctrl+R?

Comment: @cricket_007, ctrl+R works fine, thanks. But the point is that I want page up/down to work as it works in Linux.

Comment: Sorry, don't use Ubuntu, I'm not aware of that feature

Comment: Actually ctrl+R doesn't work fine... It is not good at all. Certainly not like in Ubuntu. I cannot figure out how to make it usable.

Comment: You start typing, then it completes based on your history

Comment: According to this, you edit inputrc, not bashrc https://askubuntu.com/a/745146/699350

Comment: Alternatively, if youre using Windows 10, you can download the Ubuntu terminal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was editing wrong file.

Should have edited `~/.inputrc` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Next lines in `~/.inputrc` made desirable effect:

```
    "\e[5~": history-search-backward
    "\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

Thanks [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) for pointing this out.